# Error: Feature not installed and blocking for application for using this site Template

Tags: 2013, site-template, solution-package, feature-activation, custom-solution

I have site template created from old site which is WSP file, both server versions are same(SP2013 on premise)

What is the reason behind this three feature is not installed is there any dependencies?

or any way to resolve this thing to install this feature by PowerShell

or is there any another way to create a site based on custom site template without this error?

I think these all three feature related to the branding of the previous site, shall I skip it?[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some custom features in your source farm which is not installed in your current farm that;s why it is failing. You have to option.

1. If you have all wsp(hr.branding.webparts..., roxority_filterwebpart...and hr.brand...) than install them in your current farm. after that create the site using the custom template.
2. But if you dont have the custom solutions wsps then go back to old farm and deactivate all custom features from that site then create template and use it in new farm.

Try it in your test farm 1st before applying in production.

Comment: as I don't have access to the old site, is there any alternate way to exclude these feature, like I have converted .wsp file to .cab file and comment these feature from onet.xml but cab file doesn't allow changes in them @Waqas